# Регистрация приложения в Instagram,Redirect URI

Tags: android, instagram

Для [регистрации](https://instagram.com/developer/clients/register/) приложения нужно указать Redirect URI , можете объяснить что это такое и пример.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На этот URL вас редиректнит при успешной авторизации + API Инстаграма приклеет к URL параметры для дальнейшей работы.

Для авторизации используете `WebView` и назначаете ему кастомный `WebViewClient` (я использовал `WebView` внутри диалога)

В `WebViewClient` в методе `public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)` смотрите на какой URL вы попали после авторизации, если тот что указали в консоле разработчика начинаете действовать)

```
private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        ........

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
            if(getContext().getString(R.string.redirect).contains(uri.getHost())){
                String error = uri.getQueryParameter("error");
                if(error == null) {
                    String code = uri.getQueryParameter("code");
                    //дальше используете code для получения access_token

                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(AuthDialog.this.getContext(), "Что то пошло не так", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                AuthDialog.this.dismiss();
            }
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }
    }
```